# Custom JsonFormatter in Utf8Json is ignored

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1, utf8json

I have this simple JsonFormatter:

```
public sealed class Int64StringConversionFormatter : IJsonFormatter<long> {

    public void Serialize(ref JsonWriter writer, long value, IJsonFormatterResolver formatterResolver) {
        writer.WriteString(value.ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo));
    }

    public long Deserialize(ref JsonReader reader, IJsonFormatterResolver formatterResolver) {
        var token = reader.GetCurrentJsonToken();

        if (token == JsonToken.String) {
            var s = reader.ReadString();
            return
                long.TryParse(s, NumberStyles.Any, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, out var l)
                    ? l
                    : 0;
        }

        if (token != JsonToken.Number)
            throw new ValueProviderException("The provided value is not String or Int64.");

        var value = reader.ReadInt64();

        return value;

    }

}
```

which is an implementation of `Utf8Json.IJsonFormatter<>` for working with `long` values. I've added this formatter to an AspNetCore WebApi application like this:

```
public static MvcOptions SetupCustomJsonFormatter(
    this MvcOptions options) {
    CompositeResolver.RegisterAndSetAsDefault(_formatters, _resolvers);

    options.InputFormatters.Insert(0, new Utf8JsonInputFormatter());
    options.OutputFormatters.Insert(0, new Utf8JsonOutputFormatter());

    return options;
}
```

And here is my `_formatters` and `_resolvers`:

```
static readonly IJsonFormatterResolver[] resolvers = {
    StandardResolver.ExcludeNullCamelCase, 
    ImmutableCollectionResolver.Instance,
    EnumResolver.Default, 
    DynamicGenericResolver.Instance, 
};

static readonly IJsonFormatter[] _formatters 
    = new [] {new Int64StringConversionFormatter()};
```

Also, here is my `Utf8JsonInputFormatter`:

```
internal sealed class Utf8JsonInputFormatter : IInputFormatter {

    private readonly IJsonFormatterResolver _resolver;

    public Utf8JsonInputFormatter() : this(null) {
    }

    public Utf8JsonInputFormatter(IJsonFormatterResolver resolver) {
        _resolver = resolver ?? JsonSerializer.DefaultResolver;
    }

    public bool CanRead(InputFormatterContext context)
        => context.HttpContext.Request.ContentType?.StartsWith("application/json") == true;

    public async Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadAsync(InputFormatterContext context) {
        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;

        if (request.Body.CanSeek && request.Body.Length == 0) return await InputFormatterResult.NoValueAsync();

        var result = await JsonSerializer.NonGeneric.DeserializeAsync(context.ModelType, request.Body, _resolver);

        return await InputFormatterResult.SuccessAsync(result);
    }

}
```

Everything seems to should be OK. But `Int64StringConversionFormatter.Serialize` and `Int64StringConversionFormatter.Deserializ` methods never get called. I tested the configuration with another simple formatter (say `UnixDateTimeFormatter`) and it works just fine. But I cannot figure it out why this one isn't getting called. Do you have any idea what am I missing here?